# MySQL Query: Trim a string in an entry from some start string to some end string?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query to remove '' strings from an entry up until '>' characters.

Say I have:

```
<a href='somesite'>Text Link</a>
```

The result should be:

```
Text Link</a>
```

Comment: Your best bet is to do this before you send it to MySQL. What language are you using?

Comment: @Christopher Armstrong: Or after (depends on your philosophical bent)

Comment: @Dor True. I bend philosophically many ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 SET @tmp = "<a href='somesite'>Text Link</a>";
 SELECT RIGHT(@tmp,LENGTH(@tmp)-LOCATE('>',@tmp));
```

Note: `LOCATE` finds the first occurrence of substring; that may or may not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As Christopher and Dor noted, this is almost certainly better done in your code.  Still, just for fun, here is how you might do it in MySQL.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`your_column`, LOCATE('>', `your_column`, 
  LOCATE('<', `your_column`)) + 1)
FROM `your_table`;
```